# Obscure behaviour of python in need of explanation

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have this obscure behaviour of python that I am trying to understand. I am pretty sure it is not a bug, but I can't really explain WHY it is behaving like this.
I am trying to load a few images into a list and then manipulate them.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

DATA_URL = ('./images/')

def load_data():
    data_internal = list()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(DATA_URL, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            with Image.open(DATA_URL + name) as f:

                data_internal.append(f)
                
    return data_internal


data = load_data()
print(data[0])
print(np.array(data[0]))
```

This code produces the following:

```
> <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=2x2 at 0x1EDCC735708>
> <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=2x2 at 0x1EDCC735708>
```

so
`data[0]`
and
`np.array(data[0])`
are exactly the same thing.

However, if I add a line to print
`f`
as a
`np.array()`
within the read-in, behaviour changes:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

DATA_URL = ('./images/')

def load_data():
    data_internal = list()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(DATA_URL, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            with Image.open(DATA_URL + name) as f:

                data_internal.append(f)
                print(np.array(data_internal[0]))
    return data_internal


data = load_data()
print(data[0])
print(np.array(data[0]))
```

The output of that example is

```
> [[[146 135 129]
>  [145 134 128]]
>
> [[148 137 133]
>  [148 137 133]]]
>
><PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=2x2 at 0x261491DEF48>
>
>[[[146 135 129]
>  [145 134 128]]
>
> [[148 137 133]
>  [148 137 133]]]
```

as I would expect.

Can anyone please tell me, why the mere access of the mutated (cast to numpy array) list entry makes this possible?

Thanks a lot & best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening the image files for reading using a context (`with`), and appending the `Image` object to a list.  However, once the context closes - when the `with` indentation block ends - the `Image` object closes the pointer to the file.

For speed and efficiency, `PIL` does not load in all of the image data right away, but only when needed, such as when it is converted to a numpy array.  The first time the data is requested it is read in and also saved to the `Image` object so it can be reused again.

So that is the difference, calling `np.array(data_internal[0])` while **within** the context means that the pointer to the file is still open for reading.  The data is read and saved to the `Image` object, and calling `np.array` again just returns the previously read data.

Here are 3 examples:

1. reading with no context

```
x = Image.open('pic.jpg')

np.array(x)
# returns:
array([[[ 55,  39,  42],
        [ 61,  45,  48],
        [ 55,  39,  42],
        ...,
        [110,  93,  83],
        [111,  94,  84],
        [121, 104,  94]],
...

x.getdata()
# returns:
<ImagingCore at 0x2b21acd0950>
```

2. opening within a context, but without loading data

```
with open Image.open('pic.jpg') as f
    y = f

np.array(y)
# returns a zero-dimension array of the object:
array(<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=2448x3264 at 0x2B21BA99A48>,
      dtype=object)

y.getdata()
# raises an error
...
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

3. open with context and load data

```
with open Image.open('pic.jpg') as f
    z = f
    # force loading of the data here:
    np.array(z)

np.array(z)
# returns:
array([[[ 55,  39,  42],
        [ 61,  45,  48],
        [ 55,  39,  42],
        ...,
        [110,  93,  83],
        [111,  94,  84],
        [121, 104,  94]],
...

z.getdata()
# returns:
<ImagingCore at 0x2b21a74fb70>
```

Comment: Hey, great, thanks! One additional question: What would be best practice here? Do i have to use the with-context very cautiously? Because as I understand it's sensible to use it when dealing with files. Isn't there a mantra that you should not have to have an understand of the underlying implementation when using an interface?

Comment: It is a pretty common coding practice to load the metadata and lazy-load the data only when needed.  Using the `Image` interface in a `with` context means that both `Image.open` and `Image.close` are called, just as when opening a file with a context.  Once you think about what that means: closing the file; you can understand that it is operating very much like a file object.  Just as you cannot read from a file object outside of the context, you cannot pull data from the image file outside of the context either :-)